# Creating Drop down page

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I am after creating a drop down page like on my examples below:

[image: How it shows original]

This is how I would like it to show when the arrow on the side is cliked.

[image: How I want it to show]

How would I make something like this and is there any examples any where for me to study to help me make this ?

Comment: Can you use Jquery?

Comment: W3Schools provide a nice example you can follow: http://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Im after making more of a box that moves the content below it down so it fits

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery you can play with `hasClass`, `addClass` and `removeClass` to change the height of the submenu

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/oewLqk36/).

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  if ($(".menu").hasClass("dropped")) {
    $(".menu").removeClass("dropped");
  } else {
    $(".menu").addClass("dropped");
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.dropped {
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">
  Dropdown
</button>
<div class="menu">
  <p>Stufss...</p>
  <p>Stufss...</p>
  <p>Stufss...</p>
  <p>Stufss...</p>
  <p>Stufss...</p>
  <p>Stufss...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With 3 div elements you can get a result like the one pictured. From the picture it looks like one div is wrapping around two other div elements, a div element that already has some information and a div element that will grow/shrink in size through appending/removing elements when the user presses the dropdown button.

Here is a working example:

```js
var extraInformation = document.getElementById('infoLong');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

// The extra info that will be appended into the infoLong div
var someHeading = document.createElement('h4');
  someHeading.innerHTML = 'Detailed Game Information';
  someHeading.style.background = '#C58AC5';
var teamOneInfo = document.createElement('p');
  teamOneInfo.innerHTML = 'Team 1: Lost';
  teamOneInfo.style.background = '#FF516B';
var teamTwoInfo = document.createElement('p');
  teamTwoInfo.innerHTML = 'Team 2: Won';
  teamTwoInfo.style.background = '#3FBFBF';

// Should add more detailed information when the dropdown button
// is pressed only if the infoLong div is empty
dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(extraInformation.children.length === 0){
    extraInformation.appendChild(someHeading);
    extraInformation.appendChild(teamOneInfo);
    extraInformation.appendChild(teamTwoInfo);
  }else{
    while(extraInformation.firstChild){
      extraInformation.removeChild(extraInformation.firstChild);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#infoShort {
  background: #3FBFBF;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='gameInfoContainer'>
  <div id='infoShort'>
    <h3>Game Summary</h3>
    <button id='dropdown'>Dropdown</button>
  </div>
  <div id='infoLong'></div>
</div>
```