# Fixing drop down page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a drop down page using a question asked before. 
([Creating Drop down page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324568/creating-drop-down-page)) I made it but the text that's supposed to appear AFTER the button has been pressed stays before it gets pressed. Does anyone see problems in the code?

```js
function reveal1() {
  document.getElementById('h').className = 'open';
}

function reveal2() {
  document.getElementById('i').className = 'open';
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#h {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
  background: blue;
}

#h.open {
  height: 50px
}

#i {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
  background: blue;
}

#i.open {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="reveal1()">test</button>
</div>
<div id="h">why are we here</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="reveal2()">test</button>
</div>
<div id="i">why are we here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to hide the text initially by setting the height to zero, but it will still show in the overflow. Simply add this styling to #i and #h:

```css
#i, #h {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```